# Fixing Vanilla JS Accordion to expand one tab at a time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this accordion working, however, I am trying to figure out how to expand only one at a time (click another tab, the other closes). I tried different methods to remove the class, but not getting the desired result. I have also been trying to refactor `for` loop to ES6 standards, but that's lesser of a concern.

Styling is Sass so won't output correctly in JSFiddle.

```js
const acc = document.querySelector('#accordion');
if (acc === null) {

} else {
    let accordianHeaders = acc.querySelectorAll('header');
    let size = accordianHeaders.length;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        accordianHeader = accordianHeaders[i];
        accordianHeader.setAttribute('class', 'toggle');
        accordianHeader.nextElementSibling.setAttribute('class', '');
        accordianHeader.onclick = function() {
            if (this.getAttribute('class') == 'toggle') {
                this.setAttribute('class', 'toggle-active');
                this.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("class", 'active');
                this.previousElementSibling.removeAttribute('class', 'active');
            } else {
                this.setAttribute('class', '');
                this.nextElementSibling.setAttribute('class', '');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#accordion {
    padding-top: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    li {
        width: 100%;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    header {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: blue;
        max-width: 500px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    i {
        width: 10%;
        color: white;
    }
    h3 {
        margin: 0;
        width: 90%;
        color: white;
    }

    article {
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width: 600px;
        transition: 500ms max-height ease;
        &.active {
            max-height: 1000px;
        }
    }
    .toggle-active {
        i:before {
            content: "\f106";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<ul id="accordion">
    <li>
        <header>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
            <h3>List 1</h3>
        </header>
        <article>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </article>
    </li>
    <li>
        <header>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
            <h3>List 2</h3>
        </header>
        <article>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </article>
    </li>
    <li>
        <header>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
            <h3>List 3</h3>
        </header>
        <article>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </article>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another take, using your classes (since I see you are using transitions, so I guess you want to keep your animation).

```
const acc = document.querySelector('#accordion');
if (acc !== null) {
    const accordianHeaders = acc.getElementsByTagName('header');
    let accordianActive = null;
    [...accordianHeaders].forEach(h => h.addEventListener('click', i => {
      // on currently active accordian, remove `toggle-active` from header and `active` from article
      accordianActive && accordianActive.classList.remove('toggle-active');
      accordianActive && accordianActive.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('active');
      // set currently active accordian to clicked one, and apply classes
      accordianActive = i.currentTarget;
      accordianActive.classList.add('toggle-active');
      accordianActive.nextElementSibling.classList.add('active');
    }));
}
```

Some notes about my implementation:

- I'm respecting the `#accordion` selector you use. Altough I don't recommend using `id` to match CSS (it's not recommended by BEM methodology).
- I don't remove classes from all other tags, I use a variable to keep track of the currently active tag. Maybe it's a bit more performant this way.
- I've converted your SASS to CSS to make the snippet work. Of course you can use your original SASS code.

```js
const acc = document.querySelector('#accordion');
if (acc !== null) {
    const accordianHeaders = acc.getElementsByTagName('header');
    let accordianActive = null;
    [...accordianHeaders].forEach(h => h.addEventListener('click', i => {
      // on currently active accordian, remove `toggle-active` from header and `active` from article
      accordianActive && accordianActive.classList.remove('toggle-active');
      accordianActive && accordianActive.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('active');
      // set currently active accordian to clicked one, and apply classes
      accordianActive = i.currentTarget;
      accordianActive.classList.add('toggle-active');
      accordianActive.nextElementSibling.classList.add('active');
    }));
}
```

```css
#accordion {
  padding-top: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#accordion li {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#accordion header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
}
#accordion i {
  width: 10%;
  color: white;
}
#accordion h3 {
  margin: 0;
  width: 90%;
  color: white;
}
#accordion article {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 600px;
  transition: 500ms max-height ease;
}
#accordion article.active {
  max-height: 1000px;
}
#accordion .toggle-active i:before {
  content: "\f106";
}
```

```html
<ul id="accordion">
    <li>
        <header>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
            <h3>List 1</h3>
        </header>
        <article>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </article>
    </li>
    <li>
        <header>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
            <h3>List 2</h3>
        </header>
        <article>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </article>
    </li>
    <li>
        <header>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
            <h3>List 3</h3>
        </header>
        <article>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </article>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, great solutions here, but this was what I was really looking for, replacing 'for' loop with ES6 solution with 'forEach' and 'spread'. Awesome! And yes, changed id to class as suggested. 

Now working out how to close item when clicked on again.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can do that in vanilla `Js` with lesser lines of code

```
var lists = document.getElementsByTagName("header");

for(var i=0; i<lists.length; i++){

   lists[i].addEventListener("click", accordianHandler);
}

function accordianHandler(event){
  [...lists].map(o=> o.nextElementSibling.style.display = "none");

   event.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block"

}
```

What's happening here is,

1. Attach click event to all the `headers`
2. In event handler, you can set display none for all of the `article` tags except the one you just clicked
3. As `article` is the next element to `header`, you can use `nextElementSibling` to make their display toggle or whatever

```js
var lists = document.getElementsByTagName("header");

for(var i=0; i<lists.length; i++){

   lists[i].addEventListener("click", accordianHandler);
}

function accordianHandler(event){
  [...lists].map(o=> o.nextElementSibling.style.display = "none");
  
   event.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block"

}
```

```css
#accordion {
  padding-top: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  li {
   width: 100%;
   list-style-type: none;
  }
  header {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: flex-start;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: blue;
   max-width: 500px;
   padding: 10px;
  }
  i {
   width: 10%;
   color: white;
  }
  h3 {
   margin: 0;
   width: 90%;
   color: white;
  }

  article {
   max-height: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   max-width: 600px;
   transition: 500ms max-height ease;
   &.active {
    max-height: 1000px;
   }
  }
  .toggle-active {
   i:before {
    content: "\f106";
   }
  }
 }
```

```html
<ul id="accordion">
   <li>
      <header>
         <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
         <h3>List 1</h3>
      </header>
      <article>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </article>
   </li>
   <li>
      <header>
         <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
         <h3>List 2</h3>
      </header>
      <article>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </article>
   </li>
   <li>
      <header>
         <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
         <h3>List 3</h3>
      </header>
      <article>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </article>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Article `<header>`s should go inside the `<article>`s. But you just need to make a loop over all of them, close them all, then open the one you want. Here's how:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, bod, dE, M, I, Q, S, old = onload; // for use on other loads
onload = function(){
if(old)old(); // change old var name if using technique on other pages
doc = document; bod = doc.body; dE = doc.documentElement;
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
Q = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
S = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
var headers = Q('#accordion header'), sections = Q('#accordion section'), mobile = typeof onmousemove === 'undefined';
if(!mobile){
  onmousedown = function(){
    return false; // prevent image and text dragging
  }
}
for(var i=0,on=[],l=headers.length; i<l; i++){
  (function(i){
    on[i] = false;
    var h = headers[i];
    var cF = function(){
      for(var n=0,q=sections.length; n<q; n++){
        if(n !== i){
          sections[n].style.display = 'none'; on[n] = false;
        }
      }
      sections[i].style.display = on[i] ? 'none' : 'block';
      on[i] = !on[i];
    }
    if(mobile){
      h.ontouchstart = cF;
    }
    else{
      h.onclick = cF;
    }
  }(i));
}
} // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
body{
  background:#000; overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:940px; background:#ccc; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
#accordion header{
  display:inline-block; font:bold 20px Arial; margin-bottom:5px; cursor:pointer;
}
#accordion section{
  margin-bottom:3px; display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <ul id='accordion'>
      <li>
        <article>
          <header>Header 1</header>
          <section>
            Now here is where you put your text for Header 1
          </section>
        </article>
      </li>
      <li>
        <article>
          <header>Header 2</header>
          <section>
            Now here is where you put your text for Header 2
          </section>
        </article>
      </li>
      <li>
        <article>
          <header>Header 3</header>
          <section>
            Now here is where you put your text for Header 3
          </section>
        </article>
      </li>
      <li>
        <article>
          <header>Header 4</header>
          <section>
            Now here is where you put your text for Header 4
          </section>
        </article>
      </li>
      <li>
        <article>
          <header>Header 5</header>
          <section>
            Now here is where you put your text for Header 5
          </section>
        </article>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that this is the only design shown that allows you to close the same one that has been opened. Also, if you want to style the bullets you can use `#accordion{ list-style-image:url(yourURL.png); }`, then you can just add and remove a class to change your bullet image.