# In a list of accordions How to open the one clicked and close the others when the click is happening on a child element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of accordions, each one inside the header has an icon which trigger the open/close of the accordion (The icon is not always the first child of the accordion_header). How can I open the one selected and close all the others on the click of that icon inside.
The accordion is open when it has the attribute data-state="open".
Thank you!

html

```
<div class="accordion" data-state="close">
 <div class="accordion_header">
  <span class="icon-arrow"></span>
  other stuff..
 </div>
 <div class="accordion_panel">
  <p>Accordion content</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

scss

```
.accordion_panel {
 display:none;
 .accordion[data-state="open"] & {
  display:block;
 }
}
```

I would like to know the best way in js to achieve my goal.
And some tips to make a transition, since I can't use display which is the best option to create a smooth transition?
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixing Vanilla JS Accordion to expand one tab at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401182/fixing-vanilla-js-accordion-to-expand-one-tab-at-a-time)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery

You can use this one:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xbh7bx02/)

```
if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {

        // Slide the answer up

        $('.content .accordion span').slideUp(300);
    }

    // Toggle the slide of the next element to the question

    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);

    // Remove current class from the previous accordion container

if( !$( this ).parent().hasClass( 'current' ) )
{
    $('.content .accordion.current').removeClass('current');
  // Remove current class from the current accordion container
  $(this).parent().addClass('current');
} else {
    $('.content .accordion.current').removeClass('current');
  // Remove current class from the current accordion container
}
```

One more option is:

[link from css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-jquery-accordion/)